# When does the status bar get hidden?

Tags: java, android

I set an `Activity` to full screen (no `ActionBar` or `StatusBar`) like this:

In my Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
/>
```

Then in my Styles:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

This works perfectly fine. There is no `ActionBar` or `StatusBar`.

---

Here is where the issue comes in.

In my Activity `onCreate` I get the display size of the screen (`getRealMetrics`) and when I press the `Button`, I log the values, like this:

```
Button button;
int mWidth = 0;
int mHeight = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_activity);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display disp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    disp.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);


    mWidth = disp.getWidth();
    mHeight = disp.getHeight();

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("Height = "+String.valueOf(mHeight)+" Width = "+String.valueOf(mWidth));              
        }
    });

}
```

The device I'm testing with has the following screen dimensions `1920x1080`. When I press the `Button`, I get the following in my log:

```
Height = 1857 Width = 1080
```

I checked the height of my status bar and it is 63px. So that is `1920 - 63 = 1857`. In other words, the status bar is still taken into account when I press the `Button`. So, when is the status bar hidden?

Comment: Just curious to know the reason.

Comment: @TaQuangTu I have a view that is set to `match_parent`, I save this view as a `Bitmap` and the size of the `Bitmap` should be the same size as the screen. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Did you hide soft navigation bar?

Comment: There are visibility control flags and resize control flags. Not tested but I guess latter one might affect. https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#EnableFullscreen

Answer (score 0):

you can try this after "setContentView".

```
Display disp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
mWidth = disp.getWidth();
mHeight = disp.getHeight();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.